# Function _ not found in scope _

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am having trouble using a replaceable type parameter that defaults to the Modelica standard library 2D combi table. I am using OpenModelica 1.14.1. I am new to Modelica, so I am unsure whether what I am seeing is a bug or the result of misunderstanding.

The following code works fine (in that when I press 'Check Model' there are no translation errors):

```
model Error
replaceable class DefaultTable = Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable2D;
DefaultTable bob;
end Error;
```

However, this does not:

```
model Error
replaceable class DefaultTable = Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable2D;
DefaultTable bob;
DefaultTable geoff;
end Error;
```

The following error is obtained:

```
 [Modelica.Blocks.Tables: 613:7-613:57]: Function Internal.getTable2DValueNoDer not found in scope DefaultTable.
```

Comment: By adding 'Modelica.Blocks.Tables." to the function references in lines 613 and 615 of Modelica.Blocks.Tables, I have avoided the error. Those lines now read: 'y = Modelica.Blocks.Tables.Internal.getTable2DValueNoDer(tableID, u1, u2);' and 'y = Modelica.Blocks.Tables.Internal.getTable2DValue(tableID, u1, u2);' instead of 'y = Internal.getTable2DValueNoDer(tableID, u1, u2);' and 'y = Internal.getTable2DValue(tableID, u1, u2);'. I do not know why this works...

Comment: Is it possible that this is a problem with the nested lookup for package references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a compiler bug: report it at https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/newticket

It seems to work in the old frontend though (which is the default in command-line and can be turned on in OMEdit).